# On a Fragment, what comes after onResume

Tags: android, fragment

As stated in the title of the question, what comes after onResume on fragments? Is there anything similar to onPostResume of activities or any additional methods called by the OS during fragment initialization before it is fully created and ready for use?

Comment: `Activity#onPostResume` is called after `Fragment#onResume()`... so maybe `Activity#onPostResume` will suffice for whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

There is no onPostResume.  If you really need to perform some work right after, but not during onResume, you could post a Runnable to yourself using a Handler or one of your fragment's views.

Something like:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // do post-runnable stuff
        }
    };

    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.post(r);
}
```

Comment: I am no interested in doing something after onResume, I just want to know what else is being executed by the OS since I am observing a latency between the end of onResume, or even a `post` event, and when the fragment is seen physically on the screen to have completed whatever else is doing in the background.

Comment: What other work are you doing in onResume?  Are there things that should be offloaded to another thread (AsyncTask) such as loading items to be shown in a list?

Comment: Not doing anything. Just using that method to output the milliseconds elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Resume is the last called before the fragment becomes active. Take a look here for the complete list of a fragment's life cycle: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating